# Jquery txt resize from current txt size, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added two buttons to my site to resize the txt:

```
<button id="grow">Make text Bigger</button>
<button id="shrink">Make text Smaller</button>
```

Using Jquery I have tried to add to the current body font:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#grow").click(function(){
     $('body').css( "font", "x+=2" )
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#shrink").click(function(){
   $('body').css( "font", "x-=2" )
  });
});
```

Here is my body css too if that helps:

```
body {
    background: #000;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have researched a lot and tweaked the code around numerous ways, but no luck. Shouldn't this be working?

Comment: What are you expecting `x+=2` to do ?

Comment: add 2 too the body's font in css

Comment: Once you have chosen an acceptable answer it's not necessary to change the title of your post as the UI of Stack Overflow changes so we know this has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/NUFXY/)

```
$("#grow").click(function () {
    $('body').css("font-size","+=2")
});
$("#shrink").click(function () {
    $('body').css("font-size", "-=2")
});
```

Comment: I had tried dropping that darn x! The addition of separating out my font-size in css it now works, Thanks